# Type converion error in assignment of a function pointer passed to the constructor

Tags: c++

I am trying something new and am hoping some veterans can guide me in the right path.  I did research but couldn't quite find the answer.

I am trying to declare a function pointer using the constructor of a class.  I am receiving the error:

> `cannot convert 'int(**)()' to 'int(*)()' in assignment`

Here is my code:

```
class A
{
   public:
   A(int (*ptr1)());
     void update();
   private:
     int (*_ptr2)();
};

A::A(int(*ptr1)()){
  _ptr2 = &ptr1;
}

void A::update()
{
  int result = _ptr2();
}
```

Comment: Off-topic, extract a minimal example. It should become obvious then.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I fail to see how this is off-topic.

Comment: It's off-topic by definition. If you click the "close" link, you will find that a minimal example is *required*. Since this isn't by far minimal, let alone complete, the question is off-topic.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - I made changes to minimize the example.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt At least now the sample [is fairly minimal and reproducible](http://ideone.com/X0MEAD).

Comment: This is better, but there's still some way to go. For example, do you even need a class? I'd say all you need is the function parametere `int(*func)()`, the variable `int(*_update_method)()` and the assignment `_update_method = &func`. If you write these in three lines and then rename `func` to `ptr1` and `_update_method` to `ptr2`, the fault becomes pretty obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want just

```
_update_method = func;
```

there, without the `&`.

---

```
_update_method = &func;
```

actually takes the address of the `int(*func)()` parameter, not the function pointer passed. Hence the compiler correctly complains that the types don't match.

Comment: Well what do you know, it worked.  Thanks for the reply.